# How to make silent sign programatically  for apk

Tags: android, signing

I want to make silent programatically sign for apk using Java desktop application, I am using this code to sign it manually

```
E:\Programing\java\Android\keytools>jarsigner -verbose -keystore keys/mahmoud-release-key.keystore image_slider.apk -keypass 123456 -storepass 123456
```

Although I put the password on a command, the jarsigner ask me again to type the password

**What the best way to make silent sign programatically ?**

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are your storepass and keypass passwords the same?  If they are different jarsigner will still prompt you for a password.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using(or willing to) Maven, there is a jarsigner plugin called "maven-jarsigner-plugin"-generally used for signing java files. You can store your keystore credentials on your maven settings and viola! Everytime you build your app, your apk gets signed. [Check this link](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/SigningAPKWithMavenJarsigner) for further details. i hope this helps